# Flutter override app locale for a specific widget only

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a multi language application supports  `Locale('en')`  (English)  and `Locale('ar')` (Arabic) , I have a `Row()` with four children :

```
Row(
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Text(
                            "1",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Text(
                            "2",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Text(
                            "3",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Text(
                            "4",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
```

when the locale is `Locale('en')` children laid out **left to right** :

[image]

and when the locale is `Locale('ar')` children laid out **right to left** :
[image]

Problem is I need children in this `Row()` specifically to be laid **left to right** regardless the current locale , is there any way to achieve this rather than build different widget based on the current locale ?

```
if(Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode == 'en'){
// build some widget
}else{
// build different widget
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by setting the `textDirection` property on `Row()` widget to `TextDirection.ltr` which determines the order to lay children out horizontally and how to interpret start and end in the horizontal direction.